# how to remove lines one by one from a JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea

How can i remove lines from a JTextArea one by one instead of all together?

I have a JTextArea which gets appended with string results from a thread, now i would like to remove one line at a time while the thread is executing.

Comment: Implement a method that finds the First "\n", get the rest from that Point clear the text area and append the text you just got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You first need to decide what should trigger the line removal.
- Should it be the addition of a new line, so that total line number is constant. If so then you should write your code to call the line removal code in the same location that where a new line is added.
- Or should it be at a constant rate -- and if so, then you will want to use a Swing Timer for this.
- Then you need to decide which line to remove. If not the first line, then you'll need to figure out how to calculate which line. The `javax.swing.text.Utilities` class can help you find out the start and finish location of every line of text in your JTextArea.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> the main concern is about how to remove it from the JTextArea, i have already calculated the start and end positions of a line that has to be deleted.But what function can assist in removing just that one line?

- You would first get the JTextArea's Document by calling, `getDocument()`
- Then you could call `remove(int offs, int length)` on the Document as per the [Document API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html).

Comment: the main concern is about how to remove it from the JTextArea, i have already calculated the start and end positions of a line that has to be deleted.But what function can assist in removing just that one line?

Comment: Thanks a lot i can see that its getting removed on a test try. now i'll try with the timer and on the proper GUI.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import javax.swing.*;

class SwingControlDemo {
String [] m; 
int i=0;
String append="";
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JLabel headerLabel;
private JLabel statusLabel;
private JPanel controlPanel;
Timer   t;

public SwingControlDemo(){
  prepareGUI();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
  SwingControlDemo  swingControlDemo = new SwingControlDemo();      
  swingControlDemo.showTextAreaDemo();
}

private void prepareGUI(){
  mainFrame = new JFrame("Java Swing Examples");
  mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
  mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
  mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        System.exit(0);
     }        
  });    
  headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);        
  statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);    

  statusLabel.setSize(350,100);

  controlPanel = new JPanel();
  controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
  mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
  mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
 }

private void showTextAreaDemo(){
  headerLabel.setText("Control in action: JTextArea"); 

  JLabel  commentlabel= new JLabel("Comments: ", JLabel.RIGHT);

  final JTextArea commentTextArea = 
     new JTextArea("This is a Swing tutorial "
     +"\n to make GUI application in Java."+"\n to make GUI application in Java"+"\n to make GUI application in Java",5,20);

  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(commentTextArea);    

  JButton showButton = new JButton("Show");

  showButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
     String s=commentTextArea.getText(); 
         m=s.split("\n");
        t.start();

     }
  }); 

 t=new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    i++;
     append="";
    if(i<=m.length)
    {
     for(int j=i;j<m.length;j++)
     {
      append=append+m[j];
     }  
     commentTextArea.setText(append);

    }

    else
    {
    t.stop();   
    }
      }});
  controlPanel.add(commentlabel);
  controlPanel.add(scrollPane);        
  controlPanel.add(showButton);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
     }
 }
```